# Is there a way to leave a trace of read email to be read later by an app on the same device?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, html

I am struggling with a problem that hopefully has been faced by many before. In a nutshell, I'd like to be able to provide a user with a link in an email clicking/taping of which (specifically on iPhone) would forward a user to App Store link. If user installs an app, I'd like to have a way to fetch some sort of ID stored when link was tapped within an app itself.

Actually here is a concrete example. User Bob (`bob@d.com`) sends email to Amy(`amy@d.com`) with invite to install an app and get connected. Let's assume that Amy clicks a link and installs an app on the same device. However instead of using `amy@d.com` email, she uses `amy.other@d.com` email during registration. Bob in turn doesn't expect that and friends don't get connected.

I have a backend running so I can do redirect, etc. However I don't see an obvious way to attach some sort of ID to a URL Bob sends that sticks to installation of the app. I've seen some references to HTML5 storage but I am not positive I see how I can leverage that.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's security/privacy model for iOS is purposefully designed to make tracking like this impossible.

Sorry, but you're just going to have to find some other way where the user voluntarily gives you enough information so you can track them - perhaps you could require the user type their email address before allowing them to use your app.

That's how we do it. The user must enter their email into our server and also into the app before they can use it (our app is a client for the server, so this would be required anyway).

Comment: Yes, users do enter their emails. My efforts are to prevent Amy from entering Bob's email again in order to create a link between Amy and Bob. But I am afraid you are absolutely right. I wish I could get a unique device ID somehow that is the same everywhere, like browser and apps.

Comment: There used to be an API to access a unique device ID. Advertising companies were using it to breach privacy, so Apple started banning all apps that use the API and then eventually deleted the API in the next major version of iOS. Apps that try to find a workaround (via bugs or whatever) will also find themselves kicked out of the store eventually, or at least told to stop doing it.

Comment: For example it was possible to embed a WebKit view in your app and use cookies in the web view to track things. It didn't take Apple long to make that impossible. It looks like they're about to make similar changes to how NSPasteboard works for similar reasons.